# Не могу разобраться с QSettings(чтением данных из ini)

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qsettings

Я создал класс Config для того, чтобы он читал ini файл и хранил все настройки, а потом их выдавал всем, кто в этом нуждается. Класс под синглтоном. В конструкторе пытаюсь прочитать этот файл, но ничего не читается :( Ошибок никаких не выдает , логи ниже(0000 это выдает settings.status(), 0 - ошибки нет, согласно http://doc.crossplatform.ru/qt/4.7.x/qsettings.html#Status-enum) Подскажите, что я делаю не так, почему у меня не читается?(в переменной DBHostName оказывается пустота)

linux,Qt 5.15.3 (GCC 11.2.0, 64 бита)

```
class Config
{
public:
    static Config* Pointer();
private:
    static Config* uniqPointer;
    Config();
};

Config* Config::uniqPointer = 0;

Config* Config::Pointer()
{
    if (uniqPointer == 0) {
        uniqPointer = new Config();
    }
    return uniqPointer;
}


Config::Config()
{
    QSettings settings( "./setting.ini", QSettings::IniFormat);

    int a = settings.status();
    std::cout << a;

    settings.beginGroup( "GLOBAL" );
    a = settings.status();
    std::cout << a;
    std::string  DBHostNameIP = settings.value( "DBHostName","").toString().toStdString();
    a = settings.status();
    std::cout << a;

    settings.endGroup();
    a = settings.status();
    std::cout << a;

    std::cout << "\n Config Created\nDBHostNameIP\n ";
    std::cout << DBHostNameIP << "\n\n\n\n";
    std::cout << "\n DBPort\n ";
    std::cout << DBHostNameIP << "\n\n\n\n";
}
```

код из main

```
Config* Conf = Config :: Pointer();
```

Вывод программы (логи) :

```
qwe
0000
 Config Created
DBHostNameIP





 DBPort
```

Содержимое ini файла

```
[GLOBAL]

DBHostNameIP = 192.168.0.22
DBPort = 228
DBName = sample
DBUserName = sample
DBPassword = sample
```

Comment: Первый аргумент в конструкторе QSettings тоже неверный.

Comment: @user7860670 а в чем проблема?

Comment: Указан относительный путь вместо абсолютного.

Comment: @user7860670
я пробовал так QSettings settings( "setting.ini", QSettings::IniFormat); 
так  QSettings settings( "/home/myUser/expl/myProj/setting.ini", QSettings::IniFormat);
так QSettings settings( "home/myUser/expl/myProj/setting.ini", QSettings::IniFormat);

так же поменял в setting.ini соответсвующую строку на 
DBHostNameIP="192.168.0.22"

Comment: Ок, с этим разобрались. *"в переменной DBHostName оказывается пустота"* - в коде вопроса нет такой переменной, там есть только `DBHostNameIP`, при этом читается в нее поле `"DBHostName"`, тогда как в ini файле есть только поле `DBHostNameIP`

Comment: @user7860670 резонно, я исправил, но пока безуспешно

Comment: @user7860670
заработало, аргумент "DBHostNameIP" перепечатал заново, вероятно там руссакая буква как-то попала или еще что-то, я не знаю

Спасибо вам огромное!!!

решение - указать верный путь (полный) -  /home/myUser/expl/myProj/setting.ini
- проверить названия полей

Answer (score 0, accepted):

как подсказал user7860670
решение - указать верный путь (полный) - /home/myUser/expl/myProj/setting.ini - проверить названия полей

Кстати, в самом ini файле можно писать значения полей как в ковычках, так и без, как с пробелом после(перед) символа "=", так и без.

Comment: абсолютный путь писать не обязательно. просто при отладке каталог запуска по умолчанию отличается от каталога с программой и ваша программа его не видит. просто настройте нормально параметры в сборке и запуске